# searching partial words from a database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I have a simple mysql search function that searches the titles of entries which I'd like to expand to be able to search against partial words...

For example lets say I search: cancel

currently it will return anything with the word cancel in the title. But ideally it should also return anything with the word cancellation in title.

Here's what I have so far...

```
function search_title_body($q){
    $q = '+' . $q;
    $q = str_replace(' ', '+', $q);
    $q = "+(".$q.")";

    $query = "SELECT *,
              MATCH(title) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
              FROM results
              WHERE (MATCH(title) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
              AND (published = 1)
              ORDER BY score DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($query);

    $results = array();


    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Check this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) from the MySQL Reference Manual. There's a comment that uses `LIKE`, although the comment author says it may be slow. You can check the responses, too.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT *,
MATCH(title) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM results
WHERE title LIKE '%$q%'
AND published = 1
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is LIKE or ILIKE functions

```
$q = "somestring";
 $query = "SELECT *,              
          FROM results
          WHERE title ILIKE '%$q%'
          AND (published = 1)
          ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Also why make a match column, num_rows will give you then number of hits.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your $q with like statement to get a query like this one

```
SELECT * FROM results
WHERE title like '%cancel%' OR title like '%otherword%'
AND (published = 1)
ORDER BY score DESC
```